# Excel addin using Angular : dist/functions.json not found

Tags: angular, webpack, office-js, excel-addins

I have an Excel Addin built using Angular framework (Typescript).
I am trying to configure it to use Shared Runtime in order to be able to use keyboard shortcuts and custom functions. I followed this link :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/configure-your-add-in-to-use-a-shared-runtime
Once I try the last step, my addin does not show up, and I get an error in the console :
"dist/functions.json not found".
I used webpack to build the project and I can say with certainty that functions.json does exist in the dist folder.
Here's my manifest.xml
[image]

Here's the webpack :

```js
/* eslint-disable no-undef */

const devCerts = require("office-addin-dev-certs");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const CustomFunctionsMetadataPlugin = require("custom-functions-metadata-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

const urlDev = "https://localhost:3000/";
const urlProd = "https://www.contoso.com/"; // CHANGE THIS TO YOUR PRODUCTION DEPLOYMENT LOCATION

/* global require, module, process, __dirname */

async function getHttpsOptions() {
    const httpsOptions = await devCerts.getHttpsServerOptions();
    return {cacert: httpsOptions.ca, key: httpsOptions.key, cert: httpsOptions.cert};
}

module.exports = async (env, options) => {
    const dev = options.mode === "development";
    const buildType = dev ? "dev" : "prod";
    const config = {
        devtool: "source-map",
        entry: {
            polyfill: ["core-js/stable", "regenerator-runtime/runtime"],
            functions: "./src/functions/functions.js",
            commands: "./src/commands/commands.js",
        },
        output: {
            devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: "webpack:///[resource-path]?[loaders]",
            clean: true,
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".html", ".js"],
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: {
                        loader: "babel-loader",
                        options: {
                            presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
                        },
                    },
                },
                {
                    test: /\.html$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: "html-loader",
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$/,
                    type: "asset/resource",
                    generator: {
                        filename: "assets/[name][ext][query]",
                    },
                },
            ],
        },
        plugins: [
            new CustomFunctionsMetadataPlugin({
                output: "functions.json",
                input: "./src/functions/functions.js",
            }),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                filename: "index.html",
                template: "./src/index.html",
                chunks: ["polyfill", "commands", "functions"],
            }),
            new CopyWebpackPlugin({
                patterns: [
                    {
                        from: "manifest*.xml",
                        to: "[name]." + buildType + "[ext]",
                        transform(content) {
                            if (dev) {
                                return content;
                            } else {
                                return content.toString().replace(new RegExp(urlDev, "g"), urlProd);
                            }
                        },
                    },
                ],
            })
        ],
        devServer: {
            static: [__dirname],
            headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            },
            https: env.WEBPACK_BUILD || options.https !== undefined ? options.https : await getHttpsOptions(),
            port: process.env.npm_package_config_dev_server_port || 3000,
        },
    };

    return config;
};
```

If I paste the direct path into a browser I get this error
[image]

Comment: If you put that complete path to the functions.json in the address bar of a browser when the add-in is running, does it find the file?

Comment: Is that possible in Angular based applications ? It just redirects you to another default page and prompts the error "path undefined"

Comment: Be sure you are familiar with this article: [Develop Office Add-ins with Angular](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/develop/add-ins-with-angular2). I'll see if I can get some help internally in Microsoft.

Comment: Please specify more precisely what you mean by "last step". There's more than one stepped procedure in the article.

Comment: Also, can you share your webpack.config.js?

Comment: Thank you @RickKirkham for your answer.
Yes I am familiar with that particular link.
By last step I mean "Test your add-in changes", Basically once I build the project and run it I keep getting the error functions.json not found, wherever the file is.
I even tried manually writing it and changing its path within the manifest and the project.

Comment: I'll add the webpack config, but I also tried adding the files manually without building the project, nothing seems to bypass the issue.

Comment: Experts internally are asking exactly what you see when you paste `https://localhost:3000/dist/functions.jsong` into a browser. Also, if you remove the `/dist` from the two functions URLs in the manifest, does that change anything?

Comment: Well pasting that link directly into a browser wouldn't work at all because the application is meant to be loaded within an office application. If I disable that and turn it into a normal web application however, I get this a path not found error (I'll add it into the post).
Removing the dist or changing the paths manually does not change anything, the file can't be found still

Comment: Pasting the link into a browser is just a troubleshooting step to see if the file is being served at that URL. It isn't. Try pasting `https://localhost:3000/functions.json` into a browser.

Comment: As I understand it the tutorial that you linked to does not create an Angular-based add-in. If you follow the tutorial exactly as it is, does it work?

Comment: The tutorial describes how to configure an add-in to use shared runtime to use custom functions and keyboard shortcuts. I skipped the first step because my add-in is already generated using yo office (with angular framework)
I tried pasting the link into a browser, it's still the same error (minus the "/dist").